# Pytorch gradient error: nonetype unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, gradient

I get the following error message when i run the code given below. The code is a part of a bigger code but essentially i am computing gradients here. The variable displacements and colloc_points are of the type: tensor([[-0.0819,  0.1623,  0.1228]], grad_fn=),
tensor([[-0.0556,  2.2222,  0.1667]], requires_grad=True) respectively. How do i resolve this error?

> ---> 43   eps_xy = 0.5*(u_y+v_x)

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
> ```

````
  u = displacement[0,0]
  v = displacement[0,1]
  w = displacement[0,2]

  print(colloc_point)

  x = colloc_point[0,0]
  y = colloc_point[0,1]
  z = colloc_point[0,2]


  ## Compute gradients

  u_y = torch.autograd.grad(u, y, create_graph=True,allow_unused=True)[0]
  v_x = torch.autograd.grad(v, x, create_graph=True,allow_unused=True)[0]

eps_xy = 0.5*(u_y+v_x)```
````

Comment: What do you get when you print u_y and v_x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that, even if `u`, `y`, `v` and `x` require the gradient, `u` is not a function of `y` and, similarly `v` does not depend on `x`.

You can check this by setting `allow_unused=False` and see if `torch.autograd.grad` returns an error.

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the problem..Here's the error that i get when i set allow_unused=False. Here's the error: 
"RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior"

How do i fix this? I am giving my feedforward neural network an input of 3x1 vector. The first layer of the neural network has input=3 and output =60.

Comment: The error tells you that, somehow, you are not using `x` and `y` to compute `u` and `v`, so you have to check carefully your variables. Perhaps, you're overwriting them somewhere in the code, or you're passing different values to your network.